Abstract @Configuration, multiple implementations. Inject correct dependencies?
I am trying to create an abstract @Configuration of a client to reduce boilerplate. Users should only provide 2 concrete implementations of specific dependencies for this client, and the rest should be autowired and injected automatically. It is possible for multiple implementations of this client to live in the same Spring application!
I tried something like this:
@Configuration
public abstract class MyClientConfig<T> {
  public abstract MyLoader<T> loader();

  public abstract MyProcessor processor();

  @Bean
  MyClient<T> myClient(MyGenericDependency genericDependency) {
    return new MyClientImpl<>(loader(), processor(), genericDependency);
  }
}

But this sets the signature of both dependency providers (loader() and processor()) to be empty. Depending on the implementation, these are beans dependent on other beans (e.g. DB connections).
Assuming <T> is unique across all implementations, I could have each implementation define a bean of MyLoader<T> and rely on the correct generic being injected, but this does not hold for MyProcessor which does not have a generic. There is no way to distinguish between 2 MyProcessor beans in 2 different configuration implementations without resorting to ugly @Qualifier usage.
What would be the correct approach for this without forcing each implementation to repeat a lot of this boilerplate?
